# How to batch requests on Google Compute Engine using Java API library?

Tags: java, google-compute-engine

I would like to send one API request on the Google Compute Engine, instead of sending 100 requests, in order to reduce HTTP traffic.

[Here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/api/how-tos/batch) is a description of how to do this when using plain HTTP calls. I am interested in achieving the same goal using [Google's Java API client library](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/compute/v1#add-library-to-your-project)

I am also aware of [creating groups of instances](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups/) using templates, but I didn't find a way to attach extra disks that are not read-only.